# Am I fully understanding this javascript scroll tutorial?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am following a tutorial here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

and it shows how to use easing to scroll from one section/div of another on a single webpage.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"       
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../newUI/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 1000);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
  </script>
```

My question is, am I understanding this code correctly?

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../newUI/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

These are just javascript libraries libraries.

```
 $(function() {
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
```

This is creating aa new jscript function in which I have a list function(?) that I navigate by clicking.

```
var $anchor = $(this);
```

Then I create a variable which is just an instance of the list I am clicking on.

```
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 1000);
                event.preventDefault();
```

I am not sure about this part. I am not sure what .stop.animate is doing exactly. I know it is going to the left 1000 pixels but I don't understand the process.

Thanks to anyone that can clear this up.

Comment: `.stop()` stops the current animation on the element.  http://api.jquery.com/stop/ I recommend using this when using `.animate()`.  Learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @One Trick Pony'code'.animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 300)'code' so here you are just animating some funtion/property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop() just means, if it's going through any other animations, it's stopping them and then executing THAT one.

It's animating during the course of 1000 ms or, 1 second.

It's also scrolling horizontally, using the scrollLeft function and preventing the default event, meaning it's going to scroll horitonzally, using the anchor attribute as a reference (i.e.  content 1, 2 or 3) instead of just moving to the content right away ( event.preventDefault)

Notice how every div has the class of '.content' inheriting a width of 4000px.

```
scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
```

**.offset().left** returns the left position of the element, in pixels

**$($anchor.attr('href'))** refers to section#1 , section#2 or section #3, because those are the href attributes declared in the CSS properties

so what that line of code does is scroll left by X amount of pixels, depending on what number you click

Comment: Oh okay! That makes sense. I was playing with 1000 and other number trying to make it scroll farther to one side or the other and it just kept slowing down or speeding up. How could I make it scroll further over to the left? Or do I need to create a new question to ask that?

Comment: If you want to scroll further, and not to a specific container, you can always add numbers to the scrollLeft line, for example scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left + 500, would mean, whatever number you click, 1, 2 or 3, it's always going to go 500 additional pixels left to that container, if you instead want to create another container, create another Div and give it the id of section4, and a class of container, then add this line to your UL with the class of nav: <li><a href="#section4">4</a></li>